# How to scale a centred BufferedImage so it keeps its own aspect ratio when resizing the JFrame?

Tags: java, scaling

I have a resizeable window with a default size of 1280x720 and an image with a resolution of 1280x720.

If the default aspect ratio is kept when resizing, it looks fine. However, if the user happens to have a screen resolution of 1900x1080 the image scales slightly stretched and if the user has an old monitor (1024x768) it the stretching looks terrible.

What I want is to keep the image's 16:9 ratio at all times with the image in the centre and just scale the image based on whether the window's width/height is respectively longer/shorter than the default image.

Is there any way to do that well without sacrificing performance at all?

Comment: Without sacrificing performance at all? I doubt it, as you will have to use some sort of interpolation algorithm for it. How critical is performance to your application?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward.

Here are the results of my test program.

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=1024,height=576]
java.awt.Dimension[width=1600,height=900]
```

You have the original aspect ratio and the new aspect ratio.

You just get the delta of the difference of the widths and the difference of the heights, and use the smaller delta to recalculate the new aspect ratio.

Here's the test code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;

public class AspectRatio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AspectRatio aspectRatio = new AspectRatio();
        Dimension aspect = new Dimension(1280, 720);
        System.out.println(aspectRatio.aspectRatio(aspect, new Dimension(1024,
                768)));
        System.out.println(aspectRatio.aspectRatio(aspect, new Dimension(1600,
                1000)));
    }

    public Dimension aspectRatio(Dimension aspect, Dimension newAspect) {
        double deltaWidth = (double) newAspect.width / aspect.width;
        double deltaHeight = (double) newAspect.height / aspect.height;
        double delta = Math.min(deltaWidth, deltaHeight);

        int width = (int) Math.round(aspect.width * delta);
        int height = (int) Math.round(aspect.height * delta);
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

}
```